# Windows Form Application - Having to close the form and open again?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In brief words, I am writing a code in C# that initializes a lot of arrays after hitting a button. If I hit the button. It should give me a specific value according to a password that I give to the program. If I hit the same button again, it should give me the same exact value if the password is the same (If you're curious, it's Encryption/Decryption program).

The problem is that it doesn't give the same value unless I close the form and reopen it. Which makes me think of an array that is not destroyed and giving values from last run. How can I destroy everything (exactly like if I close the form) but without closing the interface? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you provide some code please so we can see what is happening

Comment: Do you really think others can better guess what part of your code is causing the problem? :)

Comment: Well it seems you are not really prepared to do what is needed to get some help.

Comment: Can hiding form solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't provide any code, answering is a bit of quessing:

- Is the array you initialized declared globally or locally? If globally try to move it inside the function (if you want the exact same data in it for each time the function is called).
- If you want to clear the array, depending on type of array, call .Clear() on it. But as long as you don't modify the content it shouldn't be necessary. If the array doesn't expose a Clear() method, use `myArray = null;`

Comment: Legend!! Thanks a lot!!! that's what I needed. Making one of the arrays local. Sorry to all others who couldn't get my question but it takes a genius to make the complicated simple!

Answer (score 0):

How about `setting the array values to null` at the end of button click handler. This is best i can think of unless got some hands on code of yours.

Comment: yep. I am currently trying to do this. It may take me sometime to find which array is the one that is causing the problem. I was thinking of something like destroying sessions for web java. I guess my question is wrong or I couldnt explain it :/